# JNI thread causing SIGSEGV Cypress fx2lp USB chip

Tags: java, c++, macos, java-native-interface, netbeans-8

What ways could I debug this JNI code? I see that it states the problematic frame is writeUSB function but I am not seeing anything wrong with this. This Java application is written for Mac and their is a JNI that was written to communicate with hardware we manufacture in house. The USB chip in our hardware is from cypress fx2lp  Cy64713. I am not sure why this is causing a SIGSEGV...

full dump here
http://pastebin.com/BbgK796a

Full source for this JNI is HERE
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/partialdata/6L69r/ucs30interfacejni

Here is the debugger console in netbeans when i plug in our hardware turn it on and then debug the application.

http://pastebin.com/TkyqZxus

Comment: Run your IDE's C++ debugger. Run the java program. Attach the debugger to the java program's process. Wait for crash. Oh, and don't post code off site because it renders this question and its answers worthless when the other site shuffles it's links or dies. Embed the code into this post. If  the code is too bit got fit into the question, you have two problems, the first being the crash and the other being a lack of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I looked at link. It's not code. Debugging code without code is very, very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling down to this part of your stack trace is fairly useful:

```
Stack: [0x000070000011a000,0x000070000021a000],  sp=0x0000700000218010,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [UCS30InterfaceJNI.dylib+0x1146]  _Z8writeUSBPP20IOUSBInterfaceStructPhi+0x46
C  [UCS30InterfaceJNI.dylib+0xfcc]  _Z15getSerialNumberPP20IOUSBInterfaceStruct+0x6c
C  [UCS30InterfaceJNI.dylib+0x2b19]  _Z14findUSBDevicesPc+0x259
C  [UCS30InterfaceJNI.dylib+0x2f40]  Java_ucs30interface_Main_findUCS30s+0x40
j  ucs30interface.Main.findUCS30s()Ljava/lang/String;+0
```

Although the argument names are somewhat mangled by the C++ compiler you can see the names of the functions that were called when the program failed.
The top one matches a function something like writeUSB(IOUSBInterfaceStruct**,int*).  Find a function like that and look for places it uses pointers. One of the pointers in that function is probably pointing to memory that was never allocated or has already been freed.

**Update**

If you can't see the problem in the top-level function it may be in the functions that call it. eg if the function that calls it (getSerialNumber) calls it with a bad pointer that could cause the same SIGSEGV. On Linux with Netbeans 8.1 RC2, I can step from java code to C++ code with a debugger. You can try it on a Mac but I am not sure if it works. Without a debugger you can resort to putting in printf's. Put one between each line of code. The prints that show up are before the bad line and the ones that do not show up are after the bad line. You should make sure all the printf's end with `\n` and you flush stdout or the print may still be buffered when the SIGSEGV occurs. You can also split the function into smaller functions called from this one which will also help narrow things down. Print the values of the variables. command being a string needs to have a terminating 0 before the end of the array it is coming from. You will probably need to see the calling code to know how long that array is. interface being a pointer to a pointer could cause a failure either by being a bad pointer or pointing to a bad pointer. It is possible the problem is in one of the functions writeUSB calls like WritePipe, if that function were inlined it might not show up on the stacktrace.

Comment: Please re read my original post... I have stated that I have investigated the writieUSB function and it seems to be fine. What I do not understand is how do i trouble shoot a JNI being called from my java application so i can further debug the JNI. Im dealing with C++ and Java here...

Comment: Sorry I missed that you already saw the writeUSB . Added some other things to try.

Comment: Thank you! I will use your tips and see what I can figure out. I am also working with Cypress as well... Ultimately i believe I'm going to have to rewrite this JNI...

Comment: Updated the original post for the netbeans debugger info.